# Congressional/Legislative Member Data Set

Tags: shapefile, data, web-mapping, administrative-boundaries, government

I am working on a web map of congressional and legislative districts. I am able to find the boundary lines but not up to date data on the representatives per legislative district.

Anyone know of such a data set and where to find it?

Comment: It would reduce a guess work, if you mention country name.

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you are searching for US. Congressional/Legislative Member dataset

[115th Congressional Districts](http://osav-usdot.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/3d49a897770842cda6acf127ffb58442_0)

> The Congressional Districts dataset as of June 30, 2018 is part of the U.S. Department of Transportation (USDOT)/Bureau of Transportation Statistics's (BTS's) National Transportation Atlas Database (NTAD). The congressional districts for the 115th Congress (January 2017 to 2019) are the third Congressional Districts based on 2010 Census data. Congressional Districts are the 444 areas from which people are elected to the U.S. House of Representatives. After the apportionment of congressional seats among the States based on

Comment: A new link for 116th Congress: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=cc6a869374434bee9fefad45e291b779 and here is the GeoJSON version: `https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/arcgis/rest/services/USA_116th_Congressional_Districts/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&f=pgeojson`